# Bean Machine Galton Box Java Display

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

A bean machine is an upright board with
evenly spaced pegs in a triangular form.
Balls are dropped from the opening of the
board. Every time a ball hits a peg, it has
a 50% chance of falling to the left or right.
Piles of balls are accumulated in the
slots at the bottom of the board.

I have the program written to where it generates the random Lefts or Rights. 
I want the output to be the basics of the like:

```
Drop a ball? Yes...
LRLRLRR
Drop a ball? Yes...
RRLLLRR
Drop a ball? Yes...
LLRLLRR
Drop a ball? Yes...
RRLLLLL
Drop a ball? Yes...
LRLRRLR

    0
    0
0 0 0
```

I have it where it displays output of the path of the ball for the Bean Machine, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to display the array that has the balls and slots with the balls in the slots...

Here is the main parts of my code, I'm not posting the typical display methods and the such because i'm sure they are not making this problem

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class BeanMachine {

        //constants 
        static final int LEFT = 0;
        static final int RIGHT = 1;
        static final char BALL = 'O';
        //constants for options
        static final int STANDARD_GAME = 0;
        static final int QUIT = -1;

        //Scanner for input
        static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //two-dimensional array to represent the bean machine
        int ballsNo;
        int slotsNo;
        char[][]slots = new char[ballsNo][slotsNo];


//***MAIN METHOD***********************************************************

public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayBanner();

    int userChoice = QUIT;
    boolean done = false;

    System.out.print("Enter the number of balls you want to drop: ");
    int ballsNo = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of slots you want in the bean machine: ");
    int slotsNo = keyboard.nextInt();



    do {
        displayMenu();
        userChoice = getUserChoice();

        switch (userChoice) {

            case STANDARD_GAME:
                dropBall(slotsNo);
                break;
            case QUIT:
                done = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Continue playing?");
        }
    } while(!done);
}//end of main method   

//***CLEAR SLOTS*********************************************************** 

public void clearSlots(int ballsNo1, int slotsNo1){
    for (ballsNo = 0; ballsNo < ballsNo1; ballsNo++) {
        for (ballsNo = 0; slotsNo < slotsNo1; slotsNo++) {
            slots[ballsNo][slotsNo] = 0;
        }
    }   
}

//***DROP BALL*****************************************************************

static int dropBall(int slotsNo) {


    int rights = 0;
    int position = 0;

    while (position < slotsNo-1){
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    System.out.println("L");
        }
                            else{                     
                            System.out.println("R");
                            rights++;   
                  }
                  position++;
    }

      return rights;

}//end of dropBall

//***DISPLAY BOARD**********************************************************    

static void displayBoard(int ballsNo, int slotsNo, char [][] slots){

    int count = 0;
    while(count<=slotsNo){
        System.out.println(slots[ballsNo][slotsNo]);
        count++;
    }
}   



    }//end of class
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of looping through your array correctly. You need to think of it as a grid, and depending on how you look at it, determines how you print it: For example say you have a grid like, `char[3][4]` you could visualize it like:

```
   0 1 2   <- this would be your columns
0 | | | |
1 | | | |
2 | | | |
3 |_|_|_|
^
| 
this would be your rows
```

Or you could visualize it like this:

```
   0 1 2   <- this would be your columns
3 | | | |
2 | | | |
1 | | | |
0 |_|_|_|
^
| 
this would be your rows
```

So it depends on where you think the the item at `(0,0)` is located. The following example assumes that `(0,0)` is located at the bottom right:

```
public class BeanMachine {

    static final char BALL = 'O';
    static char[][] slots;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int height = 10;
        int width = 5;
        slots = new char[height][width];

        // just adding some stuff in here so we have something to print
        slots[0][0] = BALL; // bottom left
        slots[9][4] = BALL; // top right

        displayBoard();
    }

    static void displayBoard() {
        // we need to loop through each row
        String columnSeperator = "|";
        for (int i = slots.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
            String row = columnSeperator;
            for (int j = 0; j < slots[i].length; j = j + 1) {
                // char seems to be initialized to ' ' so we do not need to do
                // any checks and just add the value in the array.
                row = row + slots[i][j] + columnSeperator;
            }
            System.out.println(row);
        }
    }

}
```